# Why does a 1.8mA current draw still create a blue glow in my Nixie Tubes?

Tags: current-limiting, nixie

I've created a Nixie Clock with 6 IN-14 Nixie tubes. I've run into the issue where the tubes have a faint blue glow surrounding the digits. I've heard this is due to the Nixie tubes being over-amped and may need a higher current limiting resistance.

So I went ahead and measured the supply voltage, current limiting resistances, and the voltage drop across the current limiting resistors. The tubes are supplied with `160V`. The current limiting resistances range between `21.8k` and `21.6k`. I've also measured the voltage drop across each of these resistors to range between `40.0V` and `35.7V`. Just by taking the smallest resistance of the lot and pairing it with the highest voltage drop I'd arrive at a max current draw of `40.0V / 21.6k = 1.85mA`. Some quick searches online tell me the highest possible current through an IN-14 should be `2.5mA`, and the typical current draw of an IN-14 Nixie tube is `1.7mA`. Should I go with a higher resistance just to be safe, or is this behavior normal for some nixie tubes?

Comment: Blue glow suggests there's a little oxygen in there. Overcurrent would make it brighter, as in the output vvalves in a hi-fi amp, but if it's just a dim glow it doesn't usually do any harm.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for the reply. So would this mean my tubes may be leaking? Or was that just a manufacturing fault. If it's just a manufacturing fault and no leak, will the oxygen harm the tube over time?